# Function not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

So I've been trying to learn a bit of Swift and I've been looking at functions with return types. I added this function, and it should work, but I still get the error "Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment.' I've looked at other stack overflow questions and have tried to apply their answers, but to no avail. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    func getGasPrices2(price1: Double, price2:Double, price3:Double)
{
    return "The prices are \(String(price1)), \(String(price2)), \(String(price3))."
}
getGasPrices2(3.59, 3.69, 3.79)
```

Comment: btw, in string interpolation you don't need to convert the parameters to strings.  You can, in this case just use "The prices are \(price1)..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to declare a return type. Since you want to return a String, the function needs to declare that:

```
func getGasPrices2(price1: Double, price2:Double, price3:Double) -> (String)
```

I'm sure that Apple will work on these wonderful error messages. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Alvin stated, you were simply missing the return type

```
-> (String)
```

...in the function's declaration.

I find myself doing the same thing, forgetting the return type at the end, as I'm still getting used to writing in Swift while having the function-type-declaration-first of Objective-C habit

...

Basically your function in Swift...

```
func getGasPrices2(price1: Double, price2:Double, price3:Double) -> (String)
```

...is equivalent* to

```
-(NSString*)getGasPrices2: (double)price1 price2:(double)price2 price3:(double)price3
```

...in Objective-C*

*Strings in Swift aren't exactly the same as NSStrings but both functions would be able to accomplish what you are looking to do; one in Objective-C, the other in Swift (as long as you make sure to actually return a String/NSString at the end :-)